# Sqlite Date function

Tags: sql, sqlite, cordova

I have a column with values as **9th January 2013** and so on in my sqlite database and i want to retrieve date of today and display data accordingly; any help?

Comment: It is not clear whether you want today's date which is available without the database. Or you want the date from the database? What is the issue and what you have tried

Comment: i have a cloumn name like concert_date with values ranging from 10th dec2012 to 10th feb 2013; i  want o show todays date with the corresponding values

Answer (score 1):

If your dates were stored in [the format supported by SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), i.e., `yyyy-mm-dd`, you would be able to use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE concert_date = CURRENT_DATE
```

But a string like `'10th Feb 2013'` cannot be easily constructed in SQL; you should generate it in your code (in the same way you generate date strings when inserting records).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use number as the dataType of that column. When you add new item, write:

```
var dateToBeInserted = new Date().getTime(); // return 12312412412343
```

So, query today's data:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHour(0);
today.setMinute(0);
today.setSeconds(0);//.....more
var tomorrow=new Date(today);
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);

var sql = "select * from TableName where date >= "+today.getTime()+" and date < "+tomorrow.getTime();
```

Comment: You can refer to this site to make a better DAL with SQLite: https://cordova.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20use%20nova.data